# Trouble with CSS Drop Down in IE and Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari, hover

I'm attempting to create a pure CSS drop down menu. I'll use images later, but for now I have color place holders. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. However, in IE(10) and Safari, I can't get the drop downs to show up.

I tried troubleshooting in IE and found that some of my CSS wasn't showing up in association with the nested lists that I built the menu upon. For instance, there seemed to be no CSS attributes for

```
ul#menu li > ul li:hover span
```

even when I removed "hover." So far, none of my fixes have worked, and I'm trying to avoid a complete overhaul (though I've considered it) because it does just exactly what I want in the other two browsers.

The site I'm testing can be found here: www.nimbleforce.com/public/test

When working properly (as it is in Chrome and FF) the main menu items turn to gray on hover. The first and fourth menu items have drop downs, and they turn to red on hover. In IE, the gray hover is happening fine, but there is no sign of the drop down menu at all. In Safari, it is the same, except that I do get the pointer below the main menu on hover, as though the drop down is there, but invisible.

I've validated my code and it all comes up clean except for the opacity hacks for IE. (I even tried removing those to see if it fixed it but it didn't.)

Here's the relevent HTML:

```
<div id="navBox">

    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="bookshelf"><a href="#"><span></span></a>
            <ul id="sub1"> 
                <li id="author"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li><!--by author-->
                <li id="series"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li><!--by series-->
                <li id="genre"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li><!--by genre-->
                <li id="line"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li><!--by line-->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="comingsoon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
        <li id="blog"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
        <li id="submissions"><a href="#"><span></span></a>
            <ul id="sub2"> 
                <li id="special"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li><!--special lines-->
                <li id="calls"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li><!--specific calls-->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="faq"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

And this is my navigation CSS:

```
#navBox {

    margin: 44px auto 0 51px;
    height: 47px;
    width: 1028px;

}


#bookshelf, #comingsoon, #blog, #submissions, #faq {

height: 47px;
position: absolute;
}

#menu, #sub1, #sub1 li {

    position: relative;

}


#bookshelf, #bookshelf span {


    background-color: yellow;
    width: 184px;
}

#bookshelf {

    margin-left: 49px;
}


#comingsoon, #comingsoon span {

background-color: green;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 212px;
}


#blog, #blog span {

background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 122px;
}


#submissions, #submissions span {

background-color: purple;
    margin-left: 28px;
    width: 207px;
}



#faq, #faq span {

background-color: red;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 149px;
}

#submissions span, #faq span {

    margin-left: 0;

}




#bookshelf, #comingsoon, #blog, #submissions, #faq, #bookshelf a span, #comingsoon a span, #blog a span, #submissions a span, #faq a span {

    cursor: pointer;

    display: block;
    float: left;



}
#bookshelf a span, #comingsoon a span, #blog a span, #submissions a span, #faq a span {


height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#bookshelf a span {


    background-color: gray;
}





#comingsoon a span {


    background-color: gray;
}




#blog a span {


    background-color: gray;
}




#submissions a span {


    background-color: gray;
}


#faq a span {


    background-color: gray;
}

#bookshelf a:hover span, #comingsoon a:hover span, #blog a:hover span, #submissions a:hover span, #faq a:hover span {

opacity: 1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */

}



ul#menu li
{
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;

}


#sub2 li {

    margin-left: 0;

}

ul#menu li > ul span {

    left:0;

    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease;
}


ul#menu li > ul li:hover span {

    background-color: red;
}



ul#menu li > ul span#sub1 {
    width: 184px;   
}

ul#menu li > ul span#sub2 {
    width: 207px;   
}

ul#menu li:hover > ul span

{
        display: block;
}
```

This is my first time here, so if I did this wrong, please bear with my noobness and let me know. I'll try to fix it right away. Thanks for any assistance you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a combination of nothing being in the spans (therefore they had no height) and the doctype I was using. I added `<br/>s` to the spans and saw progress, but IE still wouldn't play. I later resorted to finding a drop down menu that worked in IE and going line by line to see where the differences were. As it happens, I was using HTML 5 but using a transitional 4.0 doctype. I changed that and the menu worked perfectly.

Thank you, @MitchDart, for pointing me in the right direction. You were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the

```
display: none;
```

inside the

```
ul#menu li > ul span
```

css? I don't see why you would want that there if you are setting the opacity to full

Comment: Yes, I did try that. What happens (in all browsers except FF) is that the dropdowns become visible without hover. I am using display none/block to hide/show the drop downs because I didn't want them to take up room or be clickable if they weren't showing.

Comment: Also, I can see the possible confusion with the opacity there. It is there because the #bookshelf hover function uses opacity and the #sub1 is inside of the #bookshelf and was affected. I added the opacity 1 to counteract that.

Comment: I see... sorry I misunderstood the code. One thing that might work is to set a fixed height of the first li's. So ul#menu li { height : 100% }

Comment: Well that gave me odd results! It made the dropdowns show up in Safari (though nothing in IE still) but it broke the hover effects in all browsers by applying the hover effect to the area *below* the item I'm hovering on. I tried going with a fixed pixel height (equivalent to 100%) but got the same results. Tried 50% and it cut everything into quarters.

Comment: Just to check, you definitely have content in the spans of the dropdowns right? like any text? If there is no text there then it will height 0

Comment: I don't. I intend to use CSS (background-image) to represent the menu buttons. (Is there a way to put content in a span for this purpose without it being seen or used otherwise?) It seems like this is the correct tree up which to bark. :) I'll try giving the individual spans a height and see if I can get better results.

Comment: If you dont want to put content then just put a <br/> tag in each span and you are sorted ;)

Comment: Thank you for that tip! I have wondered about content-less spans for some time now. Unfortunately, it did nothing for the issue in IE and Safari. One thing that did get the dropdowns to show up (but otherwise broke them horribly in all browsers) was making the 'ul#menu li {height: auto;}' However, the dropdowns acted all kinds of weird, pushing other content out of the way, and in IE going the full height of the page.

Comment: That is very strange. it worked for me on IE when I added the <br/>'s

Comment: That is odd. I put them inside every span, with no change in either browser. Even checked to be sure it loaded the new html. I think I'll take an analog break. My eyes are crossing. I'll look again when I'm fresh. I'd upvote this entry as helpful (because it was) but I don't have the rep here yet to do that. Thank you for taking the time to help me.